# Is it "anybody have plans" or "anybody has plans"?

Tags: verb-agreement

When the word *does* is skipped in a question and starts with *anybody*, what form of the verb *have* should be used?
 I thought a sentence like

> Anybody have plans to stare at their phone somewhere exciting this weekend?

would require *has*.

(The source of the sentence I'm asking about: https://www.facebook.com/100002742923/photos/a.10151612231957924.1073741825.100002742923/10152619272742924/?type=1&fref=nf&pnref=story)

Comment: In a question, it's "have"; in a declarative, it's "has".

Comment: @GregLee Sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: @DJClayworth, I agree, essentially, with Marius Hancu's answer below.  The "have" version is what remains of a question after deleting "does", which is okay to do in casual speech.  (But "do" doesn't work.)

Comment: Why do I have -2 to my question? So it is unwritten rule? Eman below agrees with me.

Comment: _Anybody have plans._ as a statement seems ungrammatical to me; I'd want a negative or a modal, at least, outside a question frame.

Answer (score 1):

**Anybody have plans to stare at their phone somewhere exciting this weekend?** is correct as far as the matter about which you ask is concerned. There is an ellipsis of the word *does*. Without the ellipsis one would have **Does anybody have plans to stare at their phone somewhere exciting this weekend?** Note, please, that version with the ellipsis is very informal, though perfectly respectable.

I say that it “correct as far as the matter about which you ask is concerned," because one can always dispute about whether it acceptable to use the plural possessive pronoun *their* with the singular antecedent *anybody*, but you didn't ask about that.

Answer (score 0):

Second person: You have plans

Third person: He has plans (or she or it)

So, if I ask in a room with many people, "Does anybody have plans?" this is second person.

But if I then ask: "Do you know if anybody else has plans?" (asking about those who are not in the room), this is third person.

Both are correct.

Comment: I think my analysis is incorrect.  With "Does" in there, even the first one is third person.  (And "have" is infinitive with do-support.)

Answer (score -1):

Well, both of

"**does** anybody have a"

"**do** anybody have a"

are using "have," right?

Thus, when you remove "does"/"do", that **"have" still remains there.**

That is confirmed to some extent at

[COCA (CORPUS OF CONTEMPORARY AMERICAN ENGLISH)](https://www.english-corpora.org), where:

. ANYBODY HAVE

5

. ANYBODY HAS

3

Google Books isn't quite able to search for periods :-[

Answer (score -3):

Look!!
The word "anybody" is one of the indefinite pronouns, like: "nobody - somebody - everybody", it is always treated as singular so it takes "has" because as we know singular subjects like "he - she - it" take "has" but when we say:

1 - Does anybody have an extra pencil? - formal voice

**Notice:** 
here in no. (1) we used "does" and when we use does the verb should be put in the infinitive from "have".

2 - Anybody have an extra pencil? - informal voice

**Notice:**
here in no. (2) we just removed "does" but the verb will remain the same.

Sorry for the confusion. I was wrong!!

**Useful link:**

http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/pt-br/english-grammar/pronouns/indefinite-pronouns

Comment: Elided words are still there; they're just implied rather than explicit. And they generally do still affect grammar. And no, just sticking a question mark on the end of a declarative sentence doesn't make it a question.

Comment: I couldn't get your point. Can u explain more.

Comment: When someone asks "Anyone have a pencil?", they're simply omitting (*eliding*) the word "does". It's still there, even though it's not said, and the grammar still works as if it's there.  (That's part of how you know the word's not just gone.) Sticking a question mark on a statement, on the other hand, only works for perfunctory yes/no questions (for which the speaker expects a confirmation) or expressions of unbelief. Which one is the case depends on the context in which it was "asked".

Comment: Aha! I got it. Thnx :))

Comment: @cHao Perhaps you _were_ joking. This answer argues strongly that way.  But you can't expect people who have never come across you / your conversation to understand your mannerisms at first glance. And ELU continuously gets a new audience.